# Why are field widths important for processing speed in SPSS?

Tags: spss

I inherited a data set to analyze.  Many of the questions have the field width set to A3884.  I ran an analysis of the actual number of characters for the responses to these fields and the median is almost always well under 100.  I am trying to explain to my team that these large field widths could be why the file is so large and it takes forever to save/export.  They want to see documentation proving that I am correct about this.  I am coming up empty.

Can you recommend any explanations or resources?

Thank you!

Comment: regardless of the theoretical discussion, you could easily test this empirically: run some of your typical analyses on the original file, then run them again after this: `alter type var1 to var2000 (a388).` . If you're not sure that there was a difference in the run time, don't bother with this. If there was a significant difference, edit your post accordingly and we'll suggest ways to optimize field widths according to the content.